# python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using [google collab](https://colab.research.google.com) to learn python and machine learning. I'm trying to read the image files from ***/content/Images/*** folder but for some reason, it is giving error -

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/Images/CM148.jpg'

. Here is my code:

```
 from PIL import Image
 path='/content/Images/'
 def load_images(abs_path):
    for image in train_images: #jpg
        print(abs_path+image)
        xpath = os.path.join(path,image)
        im=Image.open(xpath)
        np.append(image_list,im)
 load_images(path)
```

I've gone through the questions here at stack overflow with similar problems. But specifying the ***absolute path*** seems to fix their errors.

I'm sure that the images are present in the folder and I think I'm specifying the absolute path. When I run this code, it gives me a little thumbnail as a preview:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('/content/Images/CM148.jpg')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Trace what the code uses, i.e. `xpath`.

Comment: Use `Image.open(os.path.abspath(xpath))` instead

Comment: Or `load_images(abspath(path))`

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a relative path when you should probably enter an absolute.